# org-datetree: is it possible to insert a datetree at point without using org-capture?

Tags: org-mode

I would like to manually create a orgmode file with date entries. Is it possible to do it without the org-capture template? Just at point?

Thanks!

Comment: Datetrees have ordering requirements, so the facilities that Org mode provides are all of the `org-find-create` variety: they find the proper place and then they create the entry at that place. There is no "automatic" facility to enter an arbitrary date tree entry at point. But you can of course just type it in. However, if you don't follow the ordering constraints, then adding more entries through the Org mode facilities might be problematic.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to be able to insert any day with day of week beside it as a heading automatically.

Comment: So is the problem then that you want to specify an arbitrary date and you want the day of the week to be calculated automatically? It would help if you gave an example: what input do you want to provide and what output do you expect?

Comment: I better explain myself :) I just want to create a heading in the form * 2021-04-28 Wed. Just that. Instead of having to do it by hand plus figuring out which day of the week it was, etc.

Comment: Just for today's date? Or do you want to be able to enter arbitrary dates? And if arbitrary dates, how do you want to specify the date? Finally, you should add all that information to your question. The objective is to have a well-defined question that does not depend on comments to make it well-defined.

Comment: Arbitrary dates that I could pick from the calendar in the format YYYY-MM-DD dayoftheweek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind what Org mode defines as `inactive time stamps` of the form `[2021-04-28 Wed]` (do `C-h i g (org)Timestamps` for more info), then Org mode has all the facilities you need:

```el
(defun ndk/org-insert-heading-and-inactive-time-stamp ()
   (interactive)
   (org-insert-heading)
   (org-time-stamp-inactive)
   (insert "\n"))

(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c H") #'ndk/org-insert-heading-and-inactive-time-stamp)
```

If you want `active`time stamps (of the form `<2021-04-28 Wed>` - see the same section above for info), just replace the call to `org-time-stamp-inactive` with `org-time-stamp`.

Both of these use the standard Org mode mechanism of popping up a calendar and letting you select a date by typing it in, or clicking on the calendar, or specifying the date using all sorts of shortcuts (e.g. `+7` or `+1w` for the date one week ahead - the docs contain much more info).

OTOH, if you want a bare date as you indicated above, you'll have to use lower-level functions to produce the output you want.

I recommend you go either with inactive or active dates and forego bare dates.

Comment: Thanks, I don't program, so I wouldn't know how to turn that output into a heading (* yyyy-mm-dd DAYOFWEEK). :( Could you help me?

Comment: Why can't you use it as-is? It *is* a heading: `(org-insert-heading)` does that. Remember: there is *nothing* special in an Org mode file - it is just text. The magic is all the functions that Org mode uses to interpret that text (as headings, lists, links, tables etc). Just put the above code in your init file, restart emacs, open an Org mode file, put your cursor where you want to create the new heading and say `C-C H`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks!